# Ajax Response: Map JSON to HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project with C# MVC and Razor views.
The following ajax request retrieves a pricelist and injects the html to the div **priceLists**:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/priceList/GetPriceList',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { deliveryDate: deliverydate },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.Lines, function (index) {       
                    // ugly code to generate html!
                    $("#priceLists").append(html);
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#priceLists").empty(html);
            }
        });
```

*This approach works.* However, it is quite messy because I'm concatenating the html string in the ajax response.

**Is there a neat way to map my json object to a html template?**

Using AngularJS solely for this problem seems to be an overkill to me.
Another approach which comes into my mind is using partial views combined with json results, but I'm not sure how this works. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I wanted to spare you, but my 'ugly' html code looks like this at the moment:

```
var line = data.Lines[index];
var html = '<div class="col-lg-12" id="' + line.HashCode + '">';
    html += '<h3> Article No.' + line.ArticleNo + '</h3>';
    html += '<div class="input-group">';
    html += '<input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" min="0" value="0" />';
    html += '<span class="input-group-btn">';
    html += '<button onclick="AddLineToBasket(\'' + line.HashCode + '\')" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></button>';
    html += '</span>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
```

Comment: What is the html your wanting to create?. And why are you retrning a `JsonResult` with html in it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Look at my EDIT. I'm looking for an approach to inject my json object (i.e. line) to an existing HTML template (or anotherwise neat(er) solution)

Comment: I haven't used it lately, but I seem to remember decent results from http://tempojs.com/

Comment: Create a template in your view with all the html (put in a hidden `<div>` and then in the success callback, `.clone()` it and update the values based on your data which should be just a `JsonResult` containing a collection of just those 2 properties

Comment: Or you could use jquery templating. Docs [here](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template#jqueryloadtemplate)

Comment: Would also recommend removing your `onclick=...` and using [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - `$("#priceLists").on('click', yourButtonClassName, function() { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `template string` to create your `html` content.

It's helpful as you can use `${}` to show the javascript variable, easy to read for `multiline` content.

```js
let line = {
  HashCode: 'adfsf',
  ArticleNo: '123'
};

var html = `
  <div class="col-lg-12" id="${line.HashCode}">
    <h3> Article No. ${line.ArticleNo}</h3>
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" min="0" value="0" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
        button
      </button>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
`;

$('#test').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
</div>
```

[More information about template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: This approach is certainly A LOT neater than my current solution, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Fabian if you need again something similar, for consistency I suggest you use the Handlebars templates
so according http://handlebarsjs.com/ examples/
a template in your case will look like this.

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each lines}}
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="' + HashCode + '">
        <h3> Article No.{{ArticleNo}}</h3>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" min="0" value="0" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button onclick="AddLineToBasket({{HashCode}})" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Compile a template in JavaScript by using Handlebars.compile

```
success: function (data) {
    var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
},
```

Get the HTML result of evaluating a Handlebars template by executing the template with a context.

```
success: function (data) {
    var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = {lines: data.Lines};
    var html    = template(context);
},
```

Be sure that you follow http://handlebarsjs.com/installation.html